# Page viewer web-part is getting downloaded in sharepoint server 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

I'm using page viewer webpart to display home page. I added new page under site pages. And I had linked this page through page viewer webpart as web page option selected. Whenever I'm opening this page its getting downloading instead of opening in the browser.

How to change this behaviour - open file in browser, not download it?

Answer (score 1):

```
I had changed html file to .aspx, now its working fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Page Viewer Web Part only in a browser that supports the HTML IFRAME element.

Please try a different browser. It shall help.

Use these tags to find more related information: 
`#sharepoint-server` `#browser-compatibility`

Comment: This feature was working fine in sharepoint 2016, after upgrade its not working.